# MongoDB local.oplog.rs query running for long time

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 node cluster(8 vCPUs, 52 GB) for mongodb(3.2.0). I was debugging couple of queries that took several seconds, I ran `db.currentOp()` to see what queries are running and how much time they are taking and I found a query regarding `local.oplog.rs` that was running for more than **4000 seconds**, following is the query in question

```
         {
            "desc" : "WT RecordStoreThread: local.oplog.rs",
            "threadId" : "139625785952000",
            "active" : true,
            "opid" : "rs0:145981225",
            "secs_running" : 4168,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("4168129663"),
            "op" : "none",
            "ns" : "local.oplog.rs",
            "query" : {

            },
            "numYields" : 0,
            "locks" : {

            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "lockStats" : {
                "Global" : {
                    "acquireCount" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(1),
                        "w" : NumberLong(1)
                    }
                },
                "Database" : {
                    "acquireCount" : {
                        "w" : NumberLong(1)
                    }
                },
                "oplog" : {
                    "acquireCount" : {
                        "w" : NumberLong(1)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Could any please shed some light on this? what is this query doing and should I be concerned?

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior on our MongoDB instance. I am wondering if this is normal behaviour.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Our servers CPU is maxing and has been for a good few days now and it says this query has been running for.. 355254 seconds, no that isn't a typo, any help would be great.

Comment: No @JonathanCoffey, I could not figure out what the issue was. Actually I still see the `local.oplog.rs` query but our servers are running ok.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Thanks for the reply, did everything just resolve itself after some time or is it still taking several seconds?

Comment: @JonathanCoffey actually I was debugging some another query which was taking lot of time because I did not create the index and at the same time I came across `local.oplog.rs` query and was curious about it. Everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are threads related to replication. They're part of ***normal*** operation.

- `WT RecordStoreThread: local.oplog.rs`
- `rsSync`
- `rsBackgroundSync`
- `ReplBatcher`

There's actually an open bug about showing these results by default when they should probably be hidden because they're always long running operations: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28257

From the bug report:

> At present `db.currentOp()` by default shows replication-related threads
>   such as:
>
> `"WT RecordStoreThread: local.oplog.rs"`
>
> `"rsSync"`
>
> `"rsBackgroundSync"`
>
> `"ReplBatcher"`
>
> Often these operations are long running and users may get a wrong
>   impression that there is a performance problem.